# IAR STM8 LED Pin On/Off Flash

Tags: led, gpio, iar, stm8

i tried to flash the LED of this controller:

http://www.cnx-software.com/2015/01/18/one-dollar-development-board/ (as you can see, there is a led connected to PD3)

with this code:

http://pastebin.com/nCevevxN

but it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the STMicro chips. But if you are using an IDE it should have a debug mode and if you are lucky a simulator? If so that will help you pinpoint your error. Just as an example in the ATmega behaviour of the pins/ports changes between the ATmega32 and ATmega328. So the syntax might be subtly different.

Answer (score 1):

Add Delay after turning off the LED, then only you can notice the blinking.

Comment: Good idea but it still doesn't work :(
http://pastebin.com/8tRReSYK

Comment: Okay, i forgot this line:

"PD_CR1_C13 = 1;" (Push-Pull mode for Pin3)

Now this code works fine although it looks like my LED stopped working (as i posted in the initial post the LED is connected to PD3). If i connect my LCD display it starts blinking:

http://pastebin.com/S1hu7xke